# WINAPI EnumWindowsProc: Non-Standard Syntax; use & to create a point to a member

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I keep getting an error when I call  EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, 0);
Which converts my BOOL CALLBACK selectionWindows::EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, long lParam) function into a parameter.

I know it has something to do with the classes and selectionWindows:: but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Here is the .h

```
#ifndef SELECTIONWINDOWS_H
#define SELECTIONWINDOWS_H

#include <windows.h>
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QWidget>
#include <iostream>

class selectionWindows : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    selectionWindows(MainWindow * w);
    void selectionWindows::addWindows();
    BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, long lparam);

    ~selectionWindows();

private:
        char buff[255];
    };
```

And the cut-out of the part I am having difficulty with:

```
BOOL CALLBACK selectionWindows::EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, long lParam) {

    if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
        GetWindowTextW(hWnd, (LPWSTR) buff, 254);
    return true;

}    

void selectionWindows::addWindows() {

       EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, 0); //Here is the error

        for (int i = 0; i  != 254; ++i) {
            qDebug() << buff[i];
        }
    }
```

I have included windows.h & iostream

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you could minimize this example and remove `Qt` completely. The problem is about `winapi`

Comment: `EnumWindowsProc` should be a static function. If you want access to the object pass this as the second parameter to EnumWindows.

Comment: That seemed to fix the problem but created three more in the process... but that's on me. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 6):

[EnumWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497.aspx) expects a free function or static class member as the *WindowsEnumProc*. You cannot pass a non-static class member. If you need access to a class instance from within your *WindowsEnumProc*, pass a pointer to it along in the call to `EnumWindows`. The *lParam* is

> An application-defined value to be passed to the callback function.

This is an example implementation:

```
class selectionWindows : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    selectionWindows(MainWindow * w);
    void selectionWindows::addWindows();
    BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd);
    static BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProcStatic(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam);

    ~selectionWindows();
private:
    char buff[255];
};
```

The following code passes an instance pointer to the `EnumWindows` API:

```
void selectionWindows::addWindows() {
    EnumWindows(selectionWindows::EnumWindowsProcStatic, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(this));
    // ...
}
```

Where the `EnumWindowsProcStatic` forwards the call to the class instance:

```
BOOL CALLBACK selectionWindows::EnumWindowsProcStatic(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    selectionWindows* p = reinterpret_cast<selectionWindows*>(lParam);
    return p->EnumWindowsProc(hWnd);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your callback function must be `static` (or a free function), it cannot be a non-static class member method.